# filter two dataframes according to their common index

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Hi I have two dataframes. They have some common index. I would like to transform the two original dateframes into two new ones which only contains the common index. Could you help me to achieve this? Here is an example.

```
     df1 = pd.DataFrame({'one' : pd.Series([1,3,5], index=['a', 'b', 'c']),
   ....:                    'two' : pd.Series([2,4,6], index=['a', 'b', 'c']),
   ....:                    'three' : pd.Series([-4,-3,-2], index=['a','b', 'c'])});
df2=pd.DataFrame({'x' : pd.Series([1,3,5], index=['b', 'c', 'd']),
   ....:                    'y' : pd.Series([2,4,6], index=['b', 'c', 'd']),
   ....:                    'z' : pd.Series([-3,-2,-1], index=['b', 'c', 'd'])});
print(df1)
print(df2)
```

So you can see that df1 and df2 are as follows.

```
    one  three  two
a    1     -4    2
b    3     -3    4
c    5     -2    6
   x  y  z
b  1  2 -3
c  3  4 -2
d  5  6 -1
```

I would like to see them become like

```
    one  three  two

b    3     -3    4
c    5     -2    6
   x  y  z
b  1  2 -3
c  3  4 -2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i would use [Index.intersection](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.intersection.html) in conjunction with [boolean indexing](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
In [73]: mask = df1.index.intersection(df2.index)

In [77]: df1 = df1.ix[mask]

In [78]: df2 = df2.ix[mask]

In [79]: df1
Out[79]:
   one  three  two
b    3     -3    4
c    5     -2    6

In [80]: df2
Out[80]:
   x  y  z
b  1  2 -3
c  3  4 -2
```

alternatively you can use [isin()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-with-isin) fution:

```
In [81]: df1[df1.index.isin(df2.index)]
Out[81]:
   one  three  two
b    3     -3    4
c    5     -2    6

In [82]: df2[df2.index.isin(df1.index)]
Out[82]:
   x  y  z
b  1  2 -3
c  3  4 -2
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`.join()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html):

```
df1.join(df2, how='inner')[df1.columns]

   one  three  two
b    3     -3    4
c    5     -2    6
```